# compile groovy classes on the fly

Tags: java, http, gradle, groovy

I have a gradle main project with two sub-projects, one is java and the other is a groovy library.

The java project is an http server that uses the groovy libraries.

All compiles, and runs well but what I'm trying is to compile the groovy libraries on the fly (on each http request), so that I don't have to recompile everything whenever I make changes to the groovy libraries.

Is this possible?

Comment: it's possible. use GroovyShell or GroovyServlet

Answer (score 2):

It is using GroovyClassLoader. There are some caveats that I've run into when dealing with Static class fields and cross-references, but I basically use this setup on a couple of my projects. You may have to watch loading order in some cases.

```
def groovyClassLoader = new GroovyClassLoader()

def classPaths = [ '/opt/myProject/src/groovy/' ]

// First, add Class Paths -- these are the root directories of your code files.
for (String path in classPaths) {
    File dir = new File(path)
    groovyClassLoader.addClasspath(dir.getAbsolutePath())
}

def src = [ '/opt/myProject/src/groovy/net/me/program/' ] 

// Now, load groovy files
for (String path in src) {
    // Iterate differently if no access to FileUtils
    File[] directoryListing = FileUtils.listFiles(new File(path), null, false)
    if (directoryListing != null) {
        for (File child in directoryListing) {
            groovyClassLoader.parseClass(child)
        }
    }
}

// See all the loaded classes
println(groovyClassLoader.loadedClasses)
```